# Training times for Spacy Entity Linking model

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, wikidata, entity-linking

I'm trying to train a Spacy Entity Linking model using Wikidata and Wikipedia, using the scripts in https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/bin/wiki_entity_linking. I've generated the KB and moved to training the model, but that is not done yet after more than a week. How long should that take normally? (I'm not using a GPU)

Alternatively, is there a pretrained Wikidata entity linking model I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As of October 2019, Spacy does not yet provide a pre-trained model. They only offer the framework and the functionality.

I recommend you comment on this GitHub thread with your request, and your question about pre-train/training times.

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4511

Comment: Thanks. I did post a comment of the github thread, but no solution yet. I believe the issue is caused by the incredible amount of memory needed to train the model – it crashes even with more than 300Gb RAM.

Comment: You're welcome. Several people seem to have made comments referring to the memory issue. That doesn't make sense at all and simply suggests a design error in their data loader. The model itself has no reason to be that large. Hopefully they will fix the model and publish a model soon enough! :-)

Comment: The memory issue has been fixed since Jan 6: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/4811

Answer (score 1):

[This PR to spaCy](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/4811) has modifications that allow for training on a larger dataset. Instructions are also updated.

Comment: That PR is not about "allowing for training on a smaller dataset", that was always a feature. However that PR is in fact quite relevant, as it significantly reduces the memory needed to train the NEL component on a LARGER dataset.

Comment: @SofieVL Ack, typo there.. Fixed.

Comment: Ah, yes, that does make more sense, thanks for updating :-)

Comment: The question in that thread -- how many lines are needed -- do you have an estimate?

Comment: I replied to the thread as well - the experiments I did with 165K lines (i.e. articles) seem to result in a decent model.