# Pretrained Entity Linking model for Wikipedia/WikiData

Tags: nlp

I have some 34000 restaurant reviews in English to perform entity linking on and I'm looking for some scalable solution.

Is there some pretrained model for entity linking to Wikipedi/WikiData KB?

- Spacy recently started to support Entity Linking [1](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#entity-linking),[2](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/master/bin/wiki_entity_linking),[3](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4511) but they do not provide pretrained model for that and some people report [training takes at least a week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541373/training-times-for-spacy-entity-linking-model).
- [Wikifier](http://wikifier.org/info.html#wikification) has a pretrained model that can be used for entity linking via REST service for that but I don't know what's their Rate Limit for my number of texts and how it scales. Hence, I would prefer offline solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two implementations, Illinois Wikifier 1.0 and 2.0 available for download [here](https://cogcomp.seas.upenn.edu/page/software_view/Wikifier), described in the following publications

- *[Local and Global Algorithms for Disambiguation to Wikipedia](https://cogcomp.seas.upenn.edu/papers/RRDA11.pdf)*
  Lev Ratinov and Dan Roth and Doug Downey and Mike Anderson,
  ACL - 2011
- *[Relational Inference for Wikification](https://cogcomp.seas.upenn.edu/papers/ChengRo13.pdf)*, Xiao Cheng and Dan Rothm, EMNLP - 2013

I've tried the first one and got some good results. Its' definitely not production-ready software: sometimes, the memory problems accumulate resulting in Java heap space issues, but I was able to add possibility to resume failing tasks and it works great now.